# general_log table is empty,after i configure my.conf

Tags: mysql

I want to log general and slow query
my.conf is

```
[mysqld]  log_bin="/var/lib/mysql/log"

datadir=/var/lib/mysql socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock symbolic-links=0

sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

[mysqld_safe]  log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log slow-query-log=1 id-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

long_query_time=1

general_log=1 log_output=TABLE
```

But after execute some sql (the user only have select privileges),then

```
select * from mysql.general_log;
empty set.

select * from mysql.slow_log;
empty set.
```

why is empty?

Comment: You've only set `general_log=1` in `[mysqld_safe]` mode. Move it up.